# Kotlin Basic Cronometer Bug , Give Advice to Newbie

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 button and 1 textview in my layout. I had just trained, but saw some bugs. When users starts the cronometer they can unlimited click on the start button how can i fix it ?

I'm really newbie in the android development. Can you give advices for me, while i was watching my udemy lesson, i could catch the codes and basics. After that, when i try to build some basic projects for improve my skills, it gets hard. I have many syntax errors. I know what to do, but I'm confusing the order.

What can i do to do get better ?

main_activity.kt

````
    var runnable : Runnable = Runnable {  }
    var handler : Handler = Handler( )
    var number = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            //Cronometer have bugs
        // User can click the start button for unlimited

    }

    fun startTime(view: View) {



        runnable = object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                number++
                textView2.text = "$number"
                handler.postDelayed(this,1000)

            }

        }

        handler.post(runnable)
    }

    fun stopTime(view:View) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    }


}
```


activity_main.xml
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
        android:onClick="startTime"
        android:text="START"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:onClick="stopTime"
        android:text="STOP"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="109dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
 ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. If you want to prevent the user from clicking on the buttons more than once, you could disable them as soon as a click event is detected. For example, in your `startTime` method you could add

```
(view as Button).enabled = false
```

You need to cast your view to Button because the enabled property is not present in the `View` class (it comes from the `TextView` class actually, but `Button` inherits from it).

Then, you need to enable it again when you click on the stop button. You will need to retrieve a reference to your start button somehow, so you can access and enable it from your `stopTime` method. I'll leave that as an exercise for you ;).